# Iterating through a list of links in a table using Selenium - First iteration works fine and fails afterwards

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This works fine:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//table[@class='list']//td[normalize-space()='Edit']/following-sibling::th/a")).click();
```

But fails when I iterate it for a table like this:

`row.findElement(By.xpath(".//table[@class='list']//td[normalize-space()='Edit']/following-sibling::th/a")).click();`

**The HTML**:

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="list">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="headerRow">
      <th scope="col" class="actionColumn">Action</th>
      <th class=" zen-deemphasize" scope="col"><a title="Customer Name - Click to sort ascending" onclick="window.sfdcPage.wrapDhtmlWaitingRequest(null,'/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults?offset=0&amp;fpg=-1kpv5z603z3zv&amp;str=edwin&amp;sen=001&amp;sen=003&amp;sen=005&amp;sen=a0H&amp;sen=a08&amp;sen=a07&amp;sen=a0I&amp;initialViewMode=summary','/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults?offset=0&amp;fpg=-1kpv5z603z3zv&amp;str=edwin&amp;sen=001&amp;sen=003&amp;sen=005&amp;sen=a0H&amp;sen=a08&amp;sen=a07&amp;sen=a0I&amp;initialViewMode=summary&amp;srtClmn=ACCOUNT.NAME&amp;srtOrd=1&amp;relatedListId=Account','noh=1','Account','Sorting...');return false;"
          href="">Customer Name</a></th>
      <th class=" zen-deemphasize" scope="col"><a title="Customer Site - Click to sort ascending" onclick="window.sfdcPage.wrapDhtmlWaitingRequest(null,'/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults?offset=0&amp;fpg=-1kpv5z603z3zv&amp;str=edwin&amp;sen=001&amp;sen=003&amp;sen=005&amp;sen=a0H&amp;sen=a08&amp;sen=a07&amp;sen=a0I&amp;initialViewMode=summary','/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults?offset=0&amp;fpg=-1kpv5z603z3zv&amp;str=edwin&amp;sen=001&amp;sen=003&amp;sen=005&amp;sen=a0H&amp;sen=a08&amp;sen=a07&amp;sen=a0I&amp;initialViewMode=summary&amp;srtClmn=ACCOUNT.SITE&amp;srtOrd=1&amp;relatedListId=Account','noh=1','Account','Sorting...');return false;"
          href="">Customer Site</a></th>
      <th class=" zen-deemphasize" scope="col"><a title="Work Phone - Click to sort ascending" onclick="window.sfdcPage.wrapDhtmlWaitingRequest(null,'/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults?offset=0&amp;fpg=-1kpv5z603z3zv&amp;str=edwin&amp;sen=001&amp;sen=003&amp;sen=005&amp;sen=a0H&amp;sen=a08&amp;sen=a07&amp;sen=a0I&amp;initialViewMode=summary','/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults?offset=0&amp;fpg=-1kpv5z603z3zv&amp;str=edwin&amp;sen=001&amp;sen=003&amp;sen=005&amp;sen=a0H&amp;sen=a08&amp;sen=a07&amp;sen=a0I&amp;initialViewMode=summary&amp;srtClmn=00NE0000004a58n&amp;srtOrd=1&amp;relatedListId=Account','noh=1','Account','Sorting...');return false;"
          href="">Work Phone</a></th>
      <th class=" zen-deemphasize" scope="col"><a title="Customer Owner Alias - Click to sort ascending" onclick="window.sfdcPage.wrapDhtmlWaitingRequest(null,'/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults?offset=0&amp;fpg=-1kpv5z603z3zv&amp;str=edwin&amp;sen=001&amp;sen=003&amp;sen=005&amp;sen=a0H&amp;sen=a08&amp;sen=a07&amp;sen=a0I&amp;initialViewMode=summary','/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults?offset=0&amp;fpg=-1kpv5z603z3zv&amp;str=edwin&amp;sen=001&amp;sen=003&amp;sen=005&amp;sen=a0H&amp;sen=a08&amp;sen=a07&amp;sen=a0I&amp;initialViewMode=summary&amp;srtClmn=CORE.USERS.ALIAS&amp;srtOrd=1&amp;relatedListId=Account','noh=1','Account','Sorting...');return false;"
          href="">Customer Owner Alias</a></th>
    </tr>

    <!-- ListRow -->
    <tr onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" class="dataRow even first">
      <td class="actionColumn"><a title="Edit - Record 1 - NELSON,EDWIN" onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="1" data-seclkp="/001Q0000012jqBq/e" data-seclki="001Q0000012jqBq" data-seclkh="fb70693f5a4ab349f7bf6e74c4f8acff" data-seclke="Account"
          class="actionLink" href="/001Q0000012jqBq/e?srPos=0&amp;srKp=001&amp;retURL=%2F_ui%2Fsearch%2Fui%2FUnifiedSearchResults%3F_dc%3D1492761117569%26searchCount%3D1%26cmdType%3Dcmp%26cmp%3DsummarySearchResult%26cmp%3DsidetabAJAX%26str%3Dedwin%26initialViewMode%3Dsummary%26sen%3D001%26sen%3D003%26sen%3D005%26sen%3Da0H%26sen%3Da08%26sen%3Da07%26sen%3Da0I%26fpg%3D-1kpv5z603z3zv">Edit</a></td>
      <th
        class=" dataCell  " scope="row"><a onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="1" data-seclkp="/001Q0000012jqBq" data-seclki="001Q0000012jqBq" data-seclkh="fb70693f5a4ab349f7bf6e74c4f8acff" data-seclke="Account" href="/001Q0000012jqBq?srPos=0&amp;srKp=001">NELSON,EDWIN</a></th>
        <td
          class=" dataCell  ">&nbsp;</td>
          <td class=" dataCell  ">(444) 444-4444</td>
          <td class=" dataCell  "><a onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="1" data-seclkp="/005E0000005pAqf" data-seclki="001Q0000012jqBq" data-seclkh="fb70693f5a4ab349f7bf6e74c4f8acff" data-seclke="Account" href="/005E0000005pAqf?srPos=0&amp;srKp=001">webapi</a></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ListRow -->
    <tr onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" class="dataRow odd">
      <td class="actionColumn"><a title="Edit - Record 2 - NELSON,EDWIN" onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="2" data-seclkp="/001Q0000013hzA7/e" data-seclki="001Q0000013hzA7" data-seclkh="b182c705723f5e1a6f828808c22c20f3" data-seclke="Account"
          class="actionLink" href="/001Q0000013hzA7/e?srPos=1&amp;srKp=001&amp;retURL=%2F_ui%2Fsearch%2Fui%2FUnifiedSearchResults%3F_dc%3D1492761117569%26searchCount%3D1%26cmdType%3Dcmp%26cmp%3DsummarySearchResult%26cmp%3DsidetabAJAX%26str%3Dedwin%26initialViewMode%3Dsummary%26sen%3D001%26sen%3D003%26sen%3D005%26sen%3Da0H%26sen%3Da08%26sen%3Da07%26sen%3Da0I%26fpg%3D-1kpv5z603z3zv">Edit</a></td>
      <th
        class=" dataCell  " scope="row"><a onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="2" data-seclkp="/001Q0000013hzA7" data-seclki="001Q0000013hzA7" data-seclkh="b182c705723f5e1a6f828808c22c20f3" data-seclke="Account" href="/001Q0000013hzA7?srPos=1&amp;srKp=001">NELSON,EDWIN</a></th>
        <td
          class=" dataCell  ">&nbsp;</td>
          <td class=" dataCell  ">(435) 345-4543</td>
          <td class=" dataCell  "><a onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="2" data-seclkp="/005E0000005pAqf" data-seclki="001Q0000013hzA7" data-seclkh="b182c705723f5e1a6f828808c22c20f3" data-seclke="Account" href="/005E0000005pAqf?srPos=1&amp;srKp=001">webapi</a></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ListRow -->
    <tr onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" class="dataRow even">
      <td class="actionColumn"><a title="Edit - Record 3 - NELSON,EDWIN" onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="3" data-seclkp="/001Q0000014lLNc/e" data-seclki="001Q0000014lLNc" data-seclkh="36ddf075be1199f1439c154f56aa01ee" data-seclke="Account"
          class="actionLink" href="/001Q0000014lLNc/e?srPos=2&amp;srKp=001&amp;retURL=%2F_ui%2Fsearch%2Fui%2FUnifiedSearchResults%3F_dc%3D1492761117569%26searchCount%3D1%26cmdType%3Dcmp%26cmp%3DsummarySearchResult%26cmp%3DsidetabAJAX%26str%3Dedwin%26initialViewMode%3Dsummary%26sen%3D001%26sen%3D003%26sen%3D005%26sen%3Da0H%26sen%3Da08%26sen%3Da07%26sen%3Da0I%26fpg%3D-1kpv5z603z3zv">Edit</a></td>
      <th
        class=" dataCell  " scope="row"><a onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="3" data-seclkp="/001Q0000014lLNc" data-seclki="001Q0000014lLNc" data-seclkh="36ddf075be1199f1439c154f56aa01ee" data-seclke="Account" href="/001Q0000014lLNc?srPos=2&amp;srKp=001">NELSON,EDWIN</a></th>
        <td
          class=" dataCell  ">&nbsp;</td>
          <td class=" dataCell  ">(444) 444-4444</td>
          <td class=" dataCell  "><a onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="3" data-seclkp="/005E0000005pAqf" data-seclki="001Q0000014lLNc" data-seclkh="36ddf075be1199f1439c154f56aa01ee" data-seclke="Account" href="/005E0000005pAqf?srPos=2&amp;srKp=001">webapi</a></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ListRow -->
    <tr onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" class="dataRow odd">
      <td class="actionColumn"><a title="Edit - Record 4 - Edwin,Nelson" onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="4" data-seclkp="/001Q0000014jyLD/e" data-seclki="001Q0000014jyLD" data-seclkh="ebc0d5e11b734a7961e526f4db9f4ed1" data-seclke="Account"
          class="actionLink" href="/001Q0000014jyLD/e?srPos=3&amp;srKp=001&amp;retURL=%2F_ui%2Fsearch%2Fui%2FUnifiedSearchResults%3F_dc%3D1492761117569%26searchCount%3D1%26cmdType%3Dcmp%26cmp%3DsummarySearchResult%26cmp%3DsidetabAJAX%26str%3Dedwin%26initialViewMode%3Dsummary%26sen%3D001%26sen%3D003%26sen%3D005%26sen%3Da0H%26sen%3Da08%26sen%3Da07%26sen%3Da0I%26fpg%3D-1kpv5z603z3zv">Edit</a></td>
      <th
        class=" dataCell  " scope="row"><a onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="4" data-seclkp="/001Q0000014jyLD" data-seclki="001Q0000014jyLD" data-seclkh="ebc0d5e11b734a7961e526f4db9f4ed1" data-seclke="Account" href="/001Q0000014jyLD?srPos=3&amp;srKp=001">Edwin,Nelson</a></th>
        <td
          class=" dataCell  ">&nbsp;</td>
          <td class=" dataCell  ">(353) 242-3423</td>
          <td class=" dataCell  "><a onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="4" data-seclkp="/005E0000005pAqf" data-seclki="001Q0000014jyLD" data-seclkh="ebc0d5e11b734a7961e526f4db9f4ed1" data-seclke="Account" href="/005E0000005pAqf?srPos=3&amp;srKp=001">webapi</a></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ListRow -->
    <tr onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" class="dataRow even last">
      <td class="actionColumn"><a title="Edit - Record 5 - NELSON,EDWIN" onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="5" data-seclkp="/001Q0000012m1Xb/e" data-seclki="001Q0000012m1Xb" data-seclkh="4226e6544070ec8c55fdc3fec27f099c" data-seclke="Account"
          class="actionLink" href="/001Q0000012m1Xb/e?srPos=4&amp;srKp=001&amp;retURL=%2F_ui%2Fsearch%2Fui%2FUnifiedSearchResults%3F_dc%3D1492761117569%26searchCount%3D1%26cmdType%3Dcmp%26cmp%3DsummarySearchResult%26cmp%3DsidetabAJAX%26str%3Dedwin%26initialViewMode%3Dsummary%26sen%3D001%26sen%3D003%26sen%3D005%26sen%3Da0H%26sen%3Da08%26sen%3Da07%26sen%3Da0I%26fpg%3D-1kpv5z603z3zv">Edit</a></td>
      <th
        class=" dataCell  " scope="row"><a onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="5" data-seclkp="/001Q0000012m1Xb" data-seclki="001Q0000012m1Xb" data-seclkh="4226e6544070ec8c55fdc3fec27f099c" data-seclke="Account" href="/001Q0000012m1Xb?srPos=4&amp;srKp=001">NELSON,EDWIN</a></th>
        <td
          class=" dataCell  ">&nbsp;</td>
          <td class=" dataCell  ">(656) 757-5463</td>
          <td class=" dataCell  "><a onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="5" data-seclkp="/005E0000005pAqf" data-seclki="001Q0000012m1Xb" data-seclkh="4226e6544070ec8c55fdc3fec27f099c" data-seclke="Account" href="/005E0000005pAqf?srPos=4&amp;srKp=001">webapi</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Java  code:**

```js
          // Grab the table
          WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table"));
         System.out.println("table is selected");
        // Now get all the TR elements from the table
        List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        System.out.println("row is selected");
        // And iterate over them, getting the cells
        for (WebElement row : allRows) 
        {
         System.out.println("in first loop");
         row.findElement(By.xpath(".//table[@class='list']//td[normalize-space()='Edit']/following-sibling::th/a")).click();//This is where am facing problem. The element has to be clicked for each row every iteration
   
                System.out.println("element");
    
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       scrollToApplications();
           driver.navigate().back();
```

Have no clue where I am going wrong.
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here after every click you are navigating to some other page, so elements will become stale. In this case you need to initialize webelements again otherwise driver will throw Stale Element reference exception.

Also avoid absolute xpaths while finding elements.

Try code like below:

```
    WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table"));
    List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    System.out.println(allRows.size());

    // And iterate over them, getting the cells

    for(int i=1;i<allRows.size();i++){

        WebElement table1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table"));
        List<WebElement> allRows1 = table1.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        allRows1.get(i).findElement(By.xpath(".//td[normalize-space()='Edit']/following-sibling::th/a")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.navigate().back();

    }
```

Let me know if you have any queries

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the above solution.So i am taken back to the same row again and again. I am unable to iterate to next row.

Comment: I believe its the xpath that is causing the issue.  allRows1.get(i).findElement(By.xpath(".//table[@class='list']//td[normalize-space()='Edit']/following-sibling::th/a")).click();

Comment: try using allRows1.get(i).findElement(By.xpath(".//td[normalize-space()='Edit']/following-sibling::th/a"))

Comment: The xpath works when used as **driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[normalize-space(‌​)='Edit']/following-‌​sibling::th/a"))**
But when i use **allRows1.get(i).findElement(By.xpath(".//td[normalize-space(‌​)='Edit']/following-‌​sibling::th/a"))**
throws a no such element exception :(

Comment: In previous code we are searching td element in the header column also there it was th, so its throwing exception. I changed value of i starts from 1 in for loop hope it works now

Comment: Worked :) You are a star .

Answer (score 0):

when we are try to find Element with respect to row element, then i hope "//" is not required. If you used this, then xpath is changed, it will be a new element but not child of row. Try by changing path

```
row.findElement(By.xpath("td[normalize-space()='Edit']/following-sibling::th/a")).click();
```

Comment: Made changes to the above statement
row.findElement(By.xpath("td[normalize-space()='Edit']/following-sibling::th/a")).click();
This didnt work

Comment: you have to remove table[@class='list']//  you just updated the HTML code, i observed that tr is inside the table. So see updated

Comment: It works only for first row. when i navigate  back to the table to click on second row. I get following error.
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
 I believe its because am moving to a next page. But what can I do to retain the row count.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the HTML related source and error message thrown, I think it is because the xpath incorrect.

Comment: Hi, I have added the HTML

Comment: Based on other suggestions, and your answers, to prevent from getting stale element reference means that you should reget element after going back to the original page after link clicked
Probably something like this

`//get length of rows
List<WebElement> allRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[contains(@class,'dataRow')]"));
int numOfRows = allRows.length;

for (int i = 1; i <= numOfRows; i++) {
    row = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[contains(@class,'dataRow')][i]")
    row.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[@class='actionColumn']/a").click();
    driver.navigate().back();
}`

Comment: **driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[contains(@class,'dataRow'‌​)]"));** throws invalid selector error. However i tried to change the xpath but no luck. :(

Comment: you could try the xpath in chrome developer tools, 
1. right click somewhere in page , and choose inspect to open developer tools
2. Then open tab console 
3. input $x("<your xpath>") to check the correct one. 

I've tried the xpath and it seems fine

Comment: Thanks you for the response